# Google Script Error -- You do not have permission to perform that action

Tags: google-sheets, permission-denied

I've created (with help from ChatGPT) a script to run in a google sheets document so that i can click on a button and the active row will create a contact in Google Contacts.    I keep getting the permissions error.  I've given every permission that I can think of.  Signed into both apps with same name, etc.

Here's the code:

```
function createContact() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

 var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
 var data = sheet.getRange(row, 2, 1, 9).getValues()[0];

 var fullName = data[0];
 var names = fullName.split(" ");
 var firstName = names[0];
 var lastName = names.length > 1 ? names[names.length-1] : "";

 var address = {
 'homeAddress': data[3] + ', ' + data[4] + ', ' + data[5] + ', ' + data[6],
 };

 var phone = {
 'mobilePhone': data[7]
 };

 var email = data[1];
 var instagram = data[8];

 var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(firstName, lastName, email);
 contact.setAddresses(address);
 contact.setPhones(phone);
 contact.addCustomField("Instagram", instagram);
```

}

Comment: The `ContactsApp` service has been deprecated. You're supposed to use the [People API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/people) now. Still, We'd need to know the sheet structure to know how exactly this data should be read.

Comment: Thank you.   In terms of sheet structure,   B) Email Address C) Name  D) Entry Point: E) Generation  F) Street Address G) City H)  State I) Zip Code J) Phone Number  K) Instagram Handle        ----- I don't want to use D&E (Entry Point and Generation).   Does that help?  I don't know how to use People API (or what it even means frankly).  thx!